# Apply the same resources to all sub projects with Gradle multi build?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is it possible to squash or have common resource path for Gradle multi build?

This is my path structure

```
Root
+--- src
|    +---  main
|    |    +--- resources <- I want this to be common for all my sub projects
+---  Subproject 1
\---  Subproject 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution below:

```
subprojects {
  ...
  sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir "${rootDir}/src/main/resources"
  ...
}
```